# vb-created activex does not run in webBrower

Tags: vb.net, activex

I have a problem that confounds me. I have an ActiveX control that I created with VB6 that I want to host in webBrowser control via an asp file. The control is fully debugged and I have created a setup for it (though it is NOT signed).

No matter the trickery employed, it never displays. What am I doing wrong? Everything seems to be OK but it doesn’t load, it simply displays a place holder for the ActiveX control.  No doubt about it, it is correctly installed and registered. In troubleshooting I embedded a calendar control I found in the system. It worked as expected.

This led me to think that perhaps active controls created by VB cannot be used in this way. Is this thinking correct, and more importantly, how can I solve this problem? Sorry if I am long winded. I want to ensure that I make myself clear for people to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Check on the browser setting that it allows ActiveX Controls. If you are using IE you can check that Tools -- > Options.

Comment: Thanks. I did that (that was one of those things i did). For the purpose of testing, I lowered the security to the lowest imaginable). I used Calendar to verify things, and it worked OK. This made me to think, perhaps it was because I used VB6 to create it (it doesn't sound reasonable, does it?. Can anybody confirm it they have been able to host VB-created OCX controls?. Or perhaps, Is it because it is NOT signed. One more thing I want to ask is: does the settings on IE have effects on webBrowser controls? Thanks